# Problems with code bert model, the attribut device is not included in torch

Tags: javascript, artificial-intelligence, bert-language-model

I'm trying right now to use the code BERT model, to tokenize javascript code.
I read the documentation I found about the subject.

In the github I found how to code it but I have some problemes,

I tryed the code I found in the git but without success,

https://github.com/microsoft/CodeBERT

The first error is that module torch has no attribute device, how can I debugg it ?

Comment: it sounds like you're using an older version of torch ? maybe try upgrading it : `pip install -u torch`